# selecting 1 record on basis of status and calculating duration and looping the sql

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains below sample records.

```
Id | tutorid | status | timestamp
1  | 21      | online | '2017-01-01 12:30:20'
2  | 21      | away   | '2017-01-01 13:27:20'
3  | 31      | online | '2017-01-01 14:38:20'
4  | 21      | offline| '2017-01-01 15:30:20'
5  | 31      | away   | '2017-01-01 17:20:20'
6  | 21      | online | '2017-01-01 18:30:20'
7  | 31      | online | '2017-01-01 18:30:20'
8  | 31      | away   | '2017-01-01 19:30:20'
9  | 21      | online | '2017-01-01 19:47:20'
10 | 31      | offline| '2017-01-01 19:59:20'
11 | 21      | offline| '2017-01-01 20:01:20'
```

let me know how want to select timestamp from 'online' to 'offline' for each tutorid. Online is logging and presence time(where the status will be more before offline status) and offline is logout timing. away is internal status of tutor.

The output should be like

```
Tutorid | Online               | Offline
21      |'2017-01-01 12:30:20' | '2017-01-01 15:30:20'
31      |'2017-01-01 14:38:20' | '2017-01-01 19:59:20'
21      |'2017-01-01 18:30:20' | '2017-01-01 20:01:20'
```

Comment: The 'away' bits appear to be irrelevant, so I'd start by ignoring them.

Answer (score 0):

This may be incomplete, but here's a starter...

```
SELECT tutorid
     , MIN(n.timestamp) online
     , y_timestamp offline 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.timestamp) y_timestamp 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.tutorid = x.tutorid 
          AND y.timestamp > x.timestamp 
          AND y.status = 'offline' 
        WHERE x.status = 'online'  
        GROUP 
           BY tutorid
            , id
     ) n 
 GROUP
    BY tutorid
     , y_timestamp 
 ORDER 
    BY online;
```